# Position of a rainradar in google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have a problem. I have a link from a rain radar that I want to place in an iframe on my site. That works fine, but the location is not at the right place. I can adjust it manually in the folder, but I would like to have the location as standard.

This is the iframe code:

```
<iframe src="http://www.whsv.com/templates/2015_Fullscreen_Radar" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="700" width="1000"></iframe>
```

**Coordinates:**

```
latitude=52.005&longitude=5.55&zoomLevel=7
```

How can I include the coordinates in the iframe so it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are query string variables. You append them to the src url as such:

```
http://www.whsv.com/templates/2015_Fullscreen_Radar?latitude=52.005&longitude=5.55&zoomLevel=7
```

So your iframe would look like:

```
<iframe src="http://www.whsv.com/templates/2015_Fullscreen_Radar?latitude=52.005&longitude=5.55&zoomLevel=7" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="700" width="1000"></iframe>
```

Query string variables typically have a key and a value. For instance 'latitude' (key) equals '52.005' (value).

Note that before the first query string variable key/value pair there is a `?`. This separates the URL from the query string (and is not part of the query string). Following that, new key value pairs are separated by `&`.  Between keys and values, use equals (`=`).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have tried the code, but the position remains same on the folder.

Comment: Does the website you're getting that map from actually offer you the ability to use arguments on the map?  Is there a link with embed instructions?  I was assuming you already had that part worked out and knew those were the correct key/value pairs for the arguments.

Comment: No. The folder is used by many more people. I Can not contact the owner because it is not available...

Comment: honestly you'd be better off using a weather tool with a more configurable toolset.  I believe the openweather project can handle this.  What it boils down to is that if their application does not provide an API or expose those properties to allow you to use them via something like query string variables, there's nothing you can do there to customize that tool. Heres a link to the OpenWeather API. Good luck.  https://openweathermap.org/api